# Substract values from matching group

Tags: r

say I have the following table:

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(sample = c("WT_mock", "WT_mock", "WT_mock", "WT_stim", 
"WT_stim", "WT_mock", "WT_mock", "WT_mock", "WT_stim", "WT_stim"
), target = c("ref", "goi1", "goi2", "goi1", "goi2", "ref", "goi1", 
"goi2", "goi1", "goi2"), replicate = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), mean = c(15L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 15L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   sample  target replicate  mean
   <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 WT_mock ref            1    15
 2 WT_mock goi1           1    20
 3 WT_mock goi2           1    21
 4 WT_stim goi1           1    22
 5 WT_stim goi2           1    23
 6 WT_mock ref            2    15
 7 WT_mock goi1           2    20
 8 WT_mock goi2           2    21
 9 WT_stim goi1           2    22
10 WT_stim goi2           2    23
```

I'm trying to subtract the mean of each goi from my reference (WT_mock, ref) for each replicate, to create this:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   sample  target replicate  mean   dCt
   <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 WT_mock ref            1    15     0
 2 WT_mock goi1           1    20    -5
 3 WT_mock goi2           1    21    -6
 4 WT_stim goi1           1    22    -7
 5 WT_stim goi2           1    23    -8
 6 WT_mock ref            2    15     0
 7 WT_mock goi1           2    20    -5
 8 WT_mock goi2           2    21    -6
 9 WT_stim goi1           2    22    -7
10 WT_stim goi2           2    23    -8
```

I know there are several bioconductor-packages that can do that, but I want to use this as a exercise in data manipulation using R.

My approach was to `filter` for each replicate and substract the ref-value "manually", but I guess there's is a more elegant way to solve this problem (`dplyr` etc.)
My real dataset has multiple replicates and samples and I'm wondering if there's a quicker way to achive this.

Many thanks!

Comment: `with(df1, rep(mean[target == 'ref'], table(replicate)) - mean)` using @akrun's data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'replicate', create the 'dCt', by subtracting the 'mean' from the mean that corresponds to 'ref' value in 'target'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(replicate) %>%
     mutate(dCt = mean[target == 'ref'] - mean)
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   replicate [2]
#   sample  target replicate  mean   dCt
#   <chr>   <chr>      <int> <int> <int>
# 1 WT_mock ref            1    15     0
# 2 WT_mock goi1           1    20    -5
# 3 WT_mock goi2           1    21    -6
# 4 WT_stim goi1           1    22    -7
# 5 WT_stim goi2           1    23    -8
# 6 WT_mock ref            2    15     0
# 7 WT_mock goi1           2    20    -5
# 8 WT_mock goi2           2    21    -6
# 9 WT_stim goi1           2    22    -7
#10 WT_stim goi2           2    23    -8
```

Or using `match`

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(replicate) %>%
  mutate(dCt = mean[match('ref', target)] - mean)
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, dCt := mean[match('ref', target)] - mean, by = replicate]
```

---

In `base R`, we can also do

```
df1$dCt <-  with(df1,  mean[target == 'ref'][replicate] - mean)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(sample = c("WT_mock", "WT_mock", "WT_mock", "WT_stim", 
"WT_stim", "WT_mock", "WT_mock", "WT_mock", "WT_stim", "WT_stim"
), target = c("ref", "goi1", "goi2", "goi1", "goi2", "ref", "goi1", 
"goi2", "goi1", "goi2"), replicate = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), mean = c(15L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 15L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some base R solutions:

- If you always have `ref` as the first row within respective group, maybe you can try the following code

```
df <- within(df,dCt<-ave(mean,replicate,FUN = function(x) head(x,1)-x))
```

- Otherwise (`ref` is not the first row within respective group)

```
df <- do.call(rbind,c(make.row.names = FALSE,
                      lapply(split(df,df$replicate),
                             function(v) within(v,dCt<-mean[target=="ref"]-mean))))
```

Both of above will give you

```
> df
    sample target replicate mean dCt
1  WT_mock    ref         1   15   0
2  WT_mock   goi1         1   20  -5
3  WT_mock   goi2         1   21  -6
4  WT_stim   goi1         1   22  -7
5  WT_stim   goi2         1   23  -8
6  WT_mock    ref         2   15   0
7  WT_mock   goi1         2   20  -5
8  WT_mock   goi2         2   21  -6
9  WT_stim   goi1         2   22  -7
10 WT_stim   goi2         2   23  -8
```